# SUM(column) / COUNT(column) not working in Excel PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable in Excel, and I'm trying to add a custom field with a custom calcuation, but it doesn't seem to work. As of right now, the PivotTable looks like this...

```
Part        Count of Ordered        Sum of Ordered        myCustomField

ABC         4                       3500                  3500
```

The formula for myCustomField looks like this:

```
= SUM(Ordered) / COUNT(Ordered)
```

The value for myCustomField should read 875, but it's not. What am I doing wrong or not understanding about this? Also, even though this custom calculation could be added in a column outside of the PivotTable and work, I need it part of the table which is why I'm adding it through a custom field. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a calculated field like this, put another Value in your pivot table and make it the Average of Ordered.

Comment: I didn't even see that option, so thank you...works for me, but I still wonder though why my formula doesn't work in this case.

Comment: It's kinda confusing but the formula is being applied to the underlying data points, not the summary data in the pivot table. So it's doing SUM(order)/COUNT(order) individually on each order and then producing a new calculated field, which it then sums.