# ABS(column) not working in Excel PivotTable Grand Total

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot Table in Excel with a Calculated Field but the Grand Total in the Pivot table doesn't seem to work as you would expect.

You would think that the Grand Total for Column **Sum of abs value** is the Total of the cells in the column....

`abs(1) + abs(3) = 4`
IE, the **should be** column

But it seems to be ignoring that column's cells and using the data source column **[value]** or the **Sum of value** column ...

`abs(1 + -3) = 2`

Calculated Field :=

```
abs value = ABS(value)
```

pivot table

```
level     Sum of value      Sum of abs value    should be (not currently part of the pivot table)
a          1                1                   1
b         -3                3                   3
--------------------------------------------    -----
Grand     -2                2                   4
Total
```

I found this incredibly old knowledge article: [KB211470](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211470) Calculated field returns incorrect grand total in Excel. But, it has no work around.

I can't make modifications to the raw data and I'd like a solution that works with-in the Pivot Table.  I'm happy to use DAX/PowerPivot as well.  (The results are the same there by the way so it seems the cause is in how the Pivot table works.)

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Oh, And I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648990/sumcolumn-countcolumn-not-working-in-excel-pivottable answer by @joel-spolsky  but it only works for the built-in formulas under "Summarize Values by"

Comment: I tested it and it returned the correct value on my pivot table. One alternative might be to paste your pivot table values onto a new spreadsheet. I will often do this because when using a formula that references a pivot table my formula will not drag down and calculate appropriately if it is references the pivot table directly.

Comment: I recover the same behavior as @Alex using the simplest of Pivot Tables.  For me, Grand Totals and Subtotals are wrong although you can get the correct absolute value in the body of the table itself.  This is using Excel 2013 with a calculated `Field1 = ABS(C)`, where C was a field with some negatives in it.

Comment: I get the same results with a formula of `=IF(C<0,C *-1,C )` which says it may be about calculated fields and not the `ABS()` function.

Comment: Hi, @Chris2015 could you provide an example file that shows a correct value?  (Coping the pivot values to a new spreadsheet isn't feasible. )

Comment: Hi @ByronWall, yes, It's definitely something to do with a calculated field in a pivot table.   ABS() was just an example  (and in particulare, an example that can't use the the built-in formulas under "Summarize Values by" for a alternative. :) )

Comment: I guess my "solution" occurs outside the pivot table itself. I'm not sure how to resolve within the pivot table.